# Save google map in my android application to avoid loading it each time

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an android application in which i am using Google Map, the point that i want to achieve now is to avoid loading the map every time user execute my app.
How can achieve that? can any one guide me through the process of saving google map in my application or if there is another solution.

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In your application file create new mapview and destroy it.

This way you can preload map.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MapView mv = new MapView(getApplicationContext());
                    mv.onCreate(null);
                    mv.onPause();
                    mv.onDestroy();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: This will help my application consume less internet data right?

Comment: This will not consume internet. It just initialize your map.

Comment: Well i try it, it works perfect for initializing the map. But i need the whole google map services to work with (directions,..)